# djnago project showing source code instead of products

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

`When i am trying to diplay product via clicking on list instead of showing products it shows source code.

This is following view.py which is i wrote but it is not working.
but i think this code is perfect even i watch a tutorial and this code is from him but it is inch to inch copied from other guy but it is not working from me.... even im frustrated.

**View**

```
    product = Product.objects.filter(title=val)
    title = Product.objects.filter(category=product[0].category).values('title')
    return render(request, 'app/category.html', context, locals())
```

This is url page even this url is just fine i checked all of item .

**URL**

`path('category_title/<val>', category_title, name="category_title"),`

**html**

`````
{% block start %}

<div class="container my-5">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <div class="list-group">
                {% for val in title %}
                <a href="{% url 'category_title' val.title %}" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action"
                    aria-current="true">{{val.title}}</a>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9">
            <div class="row">
                {% for prod in product %}
                <div class="col text-center mb-4">
                    <a href="{% url 'product_detail' prod.id %}" class="btn">
                        <div>
                            <img src="{{prod.product_image.url}}" width="300px" height="200px">
                            <div class="fw-bold">{{prod.title}}</div>
                            <div class="fw-bold text-danger">
                                RS. {{prod.discounted_price}}/-
                                <small class="fw-light text-decoration-line-through">{{prod.selling_price}}</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </a>
                </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


{% endblock %}````
`````